# How to backup/replicate Azure store onsite

Tags: azure, backup, storage

I have a Azure website that allows customers to upload documents. There are a lot of documenet (~200Gb so far).

I need a way to backup the documents to another location (Azure or other location), or have live replication to a server. Is there anything I can use that will do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Azure storage redundancy options?  The geo redundant option might solve your replication need.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/12/04/introducing-read-access-geo-replicated-storage-ra-grs-for-windows-azure-storage.aspx

Comment: My problem is that the customer wants to have a copy, maybe on their local server. I have found something called StorSimple that may do what I am looking for. But I have been pulled off this for now.

Comment: We have a similar case. Redundancy doesn't really solve this case as data might be affected on one site and it will be synced with other nodes. The best way is have something similar to AWS' cross-bucket replication.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cloudberry](http://www.cloudberrylab.com). Here is the link to their website.  The tool will not give you cloud storage, but will assist in backup process. It can back up either to the cloud or to the local storages.